# .eventFilter(), a 'bool' is expected not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Estoy tratando de instalar un `installEventFillter` en un `QFrame` para poder hacer ciertas acciones cuando el boton izquierdo del mouse sea presionado sobre el, y que si el objeto es el `frame2` haga otra cosa.

Esto lo trato de generar con este fragmento:

```
def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj == self.frame:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print("Frame pressed")
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
                self.frame.setStyleSheet("Background:blue;")
        else:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print("frame2 pressed")
```

Sin embargo, al momento de lanzar esto me sale el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: invalid result from Main.eventFilter(), a 'bool' is expected not 'NoneType'

Process returned 3221226505 (0xc0000409)        execution time : 0.647 s
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

este es el codigo completo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QFrame,QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.frame.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.frame.resize(100,100)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("Background:red;")

        self.frame2 = QFrame(self)
        self.frame2.installEventFilter(self)


    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if obj == self.frame:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print("Frame pressed")
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
                self.frame.setStyleSheet("Background:blue;")
        else:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                    print("frame2 pressed")

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El [método `eventFilter` debe retornar siempre un boleano](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters), `True` o `False` tal como el propio error te indica.

En tu método puedes aceptar o rechazar el evento y así permitir o denegar el procesamiento posterior del mismo. Si retornas `False` el evento sigue su camino de propagación hasta el objeto, en cambio si en algún filtro uno de ellos retorna `True`, el objetivo y los filtros de eventos posteriores no recibirán el evento.

Tu método ahora mismo no retornas nada de forma explícita, pero Python retorna por defecto `None` en cualquier método o función sin un retorno explícito, por eso el error:

> a 'bool' is expected not **'NoneType'**

Mejor un ejemplo basado en tu código para verlo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QFrame,QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtCore



class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.frame2 = QFrame(self)
        self.frame2.resize(500, 500)
        self.frame2.setStyleSheet("""QFrame{background: green;}
                                     QFrame:hover{background: blue;};""")

        self.frame = QFrame(self)
        self.frame.resize(100, 100)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("Background:red;")

        self.frame.setMouseTracking(True)  
        self.frame.installEventFilter(self)
        self.frame2.setMouseTracking(True)  
        self.frame2.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                if obj is self.frame:
                    print("Frame pressed")
                    return True
                elif obj is self.frame2:
                    print("Frame2 pressed")
                    return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
            return False

        return False

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Al posicionar el cursor encima de `frame2` el color de fondo cambia según lo definido en la hija de estilos, pero si cambias:

```
elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
    return False
```

por

```
elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.HoverEnter:
    return True
```

el estilo definido para el evento hover no se aplica, al retornar `True` en el `envetFilter` el evento no llega al widget (ni a nada que se encuentre por debajo en la cadena de propagación del evento).